# How to find file location on android /system/ directory

Tags: adb, locate

I need to find a way to locate file (ex: "xxx.apk")
if it exists on android device in the system directory or one of its subdirectories.

Locate and find does not work.

I can't use busybox or any other market applications.

Tried this one:

```
ls -laR | grep "xxx.apk"
```

It can tell whether or not the file exists but it does not print its location.

Could you please help me solve this problem?

Batch, shell or Java script would be the best solution from my point of view

**Update:**
I wrote java application that search for file in SystemApp.txt created from code by @sjoy.
Im still begginer in java programing so maybe its not pretty but it works.
Thank You all for help.

Paste code below, maybe it will be helpfull for someone.

**------**

```
    private static int i=0;
    private static String file="XXX.apk";
    private static boolean found=false;
    private static String result;
    public static void main (String []args ){

        ArrayList<String>lines = new ArrayList<String>();
               File f0 = new File ("src/SystemApp.txt");
        try {
            Scanner scaner = new Scanner(f0);
            while (scaner.hasNext()){
                lines.add(scaner.next());
                if (file.equals(lines.get(i))){
                while (found==false){
                if (lines.get(i).contains("/")){
                    result=lines.get(i).substring(0,lines.get(i).length()-1)+"/"+file;
                    System.out.println(result);
                    found=true;

                }else{
                  i--;
                }
                }


            }else{
                 i++;  
                }
            }
            if (found==false){
                System.out.println(file+" not found");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Find.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }                
}
```

Comment: how about `pm list packages -f | grep "xxx.apk"` ?

Comment: Your solution works great for .apk files but i also need to locate files with extension like .jar and .so

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're willing to manually search printed ouput--and most files are apk, jar, so or odex--so ...
This batch file writes name of all files in /system to SystemApp.txt on your desktop. Directories are listed like this `/system/app` followed by all the files in the dir.

```
@echo off
    :: Just to confirm you're connected
    adb devices
    :: Write everything in /system to SystemApp.txt
    adb shell ls -R "/system" > SystemApp.txt
exit
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a way with the "find" command to get all the apk and the path name.

```
find "$(cd /; pwd)" -name "*.apk"
```